# please prove that$E_3=\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{({d_{n}\over 10^{n!}})}\mid d_{n}\in\{4,7\}\}$ contains no algebraic numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, number-theory

I have a question from my professor:

Given

$$E_3=\left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left({d_n\over 10^{n!}}\right) \mid d_n \in\{4,7\}\right\},$$

please prove $E_3$ is compact, perfect (hence uncountable) and nowhere-dense, and prove it contains no algebraic numbers.

I have proved that the set is compact, perfect and nowhere-dense, but still have no idea how to prove $E_{3}$ contains no algebraic numbers. Can someone tell me how to prove it? any hints?

Comment: A quick reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence

Comment: oh , that's general proof